# How to find the time complexity of a given program in c

Tags: c

How to find the time complexity of the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int a, b, sum;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter  2 Numbers ");
    scanf('%d%d",&a&b);
    sum=a+b;
    printf("Sum Of 2 Numbers :%d",sum);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: By the way the code don't compile, I don't changed in the edit, for not changing the code, the line `scanf('%d%d",&a&b);` should be `scanf("%d%d",&a, &b);`

Comment: What does "time complexity" mean to you? Your program can only take 2 inputs; a measurement of how it scales given more inputs makes no sense at all.

Comment: Did you study about Time Complexity Calculation before asking the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Time complexity of program is usually calculated based on the number of inputs. For the programs like one u have given, the complexity is always constant so the time complexity is O(1). Read a bit about the complexity of algorithms then u will get a clear picture. I would suggest an algorithm book by douglas e. comer, or google it and just read.